# Android: PublisherInterstitialAd and DoubleClick for Publishers by Google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads, interstitial

I am a little bit confused between interstitialAd and PublisherInterstitialAd and DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP).

DFP is found at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/

As referred in https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download, it says *"On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then."*

And so I have followed the instruction to import **google-play-services_lib** as the library in the Workspace, and referred it to my app as a library. I have also removed the `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` in a view that it will not be supported anyway later.

Though I do not know what are the difference, I have changed all my previous **interstitialAd** to **PublisherInterstitialAd** by following https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/doubleclick/PublisherInterstitialAd.html, and anyway, a full page ad is appeared and I think it is fine.

So

1. what is the difference between interstitialAd, PublisherInsterstitialAd? PublisherInsterstitialAd is just new version for interstitialAd ?
2. And what is DoubleClick for Publishers?

Thanks!

Comment: I would love to know that as well!

Answer (score 4):

If you use Google's ad services like AdSense or AdMob Google will both provide the ad from their supply of ads and deliver the ad using their technology. DoubleClick for Publishers is a service that lets publishers use Google's ad delivery technology to deliver ads without Google providing the ad. This lets publishers sell ads themselves and still use Google's technology to display these ads.

InterstitialAd is the Admob version where Google will provide the ad for you.

PublisherInterstitialAd is the version where you sell the ad space yourself and then you use google's technology to display it.